# I can not get Visual Studio, Android Device Log, or ADB to recognize my LGE Tablet (VK815)

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio-2013, xamarin

I have recently downloaded the Xamarin packages into Visual Studio and I want to test my application on a physical device rather than an emulator.  I have my LG VK815 tablet connected via USB.  However, I can not get adb or the Android Device Logging to find my tablet. adb returns `error: no devices found` when I enter the command `adb usb` and returns `List of Devices` when I use the command `adb devices`, so I think it is pretty clear that my devices is not being found.

I have my the tablet's driver updated to the newest version and I have it in Developer Mode after hitting the Model Number 7 times.  Am I missing something here?  Nothing I find online seems to give me an answer.

I have tried following the Xamarin tutorials on their website word for word, but nothing seems to be working for me.  Can anyone suggest where I can try to troubleshoot my problem?

## Edit

I have the Google/usb_driver from the Android SDK but when try to update the driver of my tablet, I get this :

[image]

I have tried uninstalling the current driver, but the same one gets installed.  IS there a way to force it to use the Google driver?

## Edit 2

[image]

I now get this error when I tell Windows to install when I "Have the disk.."

Answer (score 0):

You must install the ADB composite interface driver, by default the device is installed with standard drivers, to do development you need to use an ADB driver.

Go to your android SDK path, enter to extras\google\usb_driver and replace your device driver with the ADB composite interface one.

Comment: Thank you.  So I replace my tablet's driver with the one from the android SDK?

Comment: Yes, that's it, Xamarin does not install nothing, it's a matter with the Android SDK

Comment: Please see my edit for the result of this suggestion

Comment: You must replace the driver, not let search WIndows to find another driver. Select "Choose from a list" and then "Have a disk", even if WIndows tells you the driver is not recommended install it, then it will work.

Comment: Maybe I do not understand, but I have updated the question again with the error I get when I do that.

Comment: Strange, it should show a list of three drivers, I always installed it from there on all mobile devices I got, event LG ones

Answer (score 0):

Right click and go to properties\Driver\Update Drive\Browse For driver software...
Next,
Click on LET ME PICK FROM LIST...and dbl clk on the firs option (i think "Have Disk...") now you can browse to where ever and select what ever.

Hope this helps.